# Get-PnpDevice not working if written in file

Tags: powershell

I can run this command

```
$webcam = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName USB-Videogerät -Class Camera -Status OK | Select-Object -Property InstanceId | Select-Object -First 1
```

perfectly fine in a powershell but whenever i copy it in a text file, save it as .ps1 and try to start it as administrator i get the following error:

```
    Get-PnpDevice : Durch "CIM-Abfrage für Instanzen der Klasse "ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity" auf dem CIM-Server "": SELECT
* FROM Win32_PnPEntity  WHERE ((Name LIKE 'USB-VideogerÃ¤t')) AND ((PNPClass = 'Camera')) AND ((Status = 'OK'))"
wurden keine übereinstimmenden Win32_PnPEntity-Objekte gefunden. Überprüfen Sie die Abfrageparameter, und wiederholen
Sie den Vorgang.
In C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\Scripts\Webcam\WEBCAM_OFF.ps1:7 Zeichen:11
+ $webcam = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName USB-VideogerÃ¤t -Class Camera - ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Win32_PnPEntity:String) [Get-PnpDevice], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Get-PnpDevice
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Save the ps1 file in Utf8 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've noticed it doesn't work because of the `ä` in `-FriendlyName USB-Videogerät`.

I just pasted my code into PowerShell ISE and saved it from there, then it worked.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? Please read [answer].